# C# method that returns a SQL string without passing any variables

Tags: c#, methods

I am trying to create a method that runs a query then reads the **2** values it returns then place them in the global variables so I can access them in another page. My question is what method should I use because I have two variables to set. Typically I pass the variables that I will be using but in this case I'm not. This main seem simple but I can't think of a way to get these values. I am not sure how to look this problem up to research it either. I have included the code below what I have attempted so far. Thank you for you help.

```
public string getTotals3()
    {
        WorkerData workerData = new WorkerData();

        StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
        sqlString.Append("SELECT DISTINCT DataWin8Data, DataWin7Data ");
        sqlString.Append("FROM Data ");
        sqlString.Append("WHERE Number = 4");

        SqlDataReader reader = null;
        SqlConnection dbConn = App_Code.DBHelper.getConnection();

        try
        {
            reader = App_Code.DBHelper.executeQuery(dbConn, sqlString.ToString(), null);
            if (reader != null)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    workerData.TotalCases4 = reader["DataWin8Data"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["DataWin8Data"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                    workerData.TotalPercentage4 = reader["DataWin7Data"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["DataWin7Data"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                }
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("No records returned");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (dbConn != null)
            {
                try { dbConn.Close(); dbConn.Dispose(); }
                catch { }
            }
            if (reader != null)
            {
                try { reader.Close(); reader.Dispose(); }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        return workerData.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about a web application (`"another page"`)? Why don't you want to return the values? Using two global variables doesn't look like a good idea to me right now.

Comment: @Gorgsenegger this is another c# page I do my query connections etc. and I want to place the values in the variables so I can pass them to the page and set them. I want the values from the reader I just cna;t get both on tried two returns at the bottom didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by `page`? Another class, method, ...? Please provide more information.

Comment: @Gorgsenegger fromm my DataClass to my asp.page. this is from my DataClass where I am trying to get the data into my labels on my asp page. I need to just run a query that returns one row with two cells. From there read them place them in my global variables to be placed on my label in my asp.cs file.

Comment: This information is all missing in your question, so please add it there. You also didn't tag it with the appropriate tags, which makes it harder for others to find.

Comment: @Gorgsenegger I'm still learning what to include or what is relevant in a post. I apologize.

Comment: You seem to be having trouble understanding how to return more than one value. You can't return two values, but you can either return an object, a collection or an array.

Comment: It looks like your DBHelper type is very seriously flawed, and forces you to write code that will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. This is a very serious problem. I don't get to see the whole picture in your sample, so you may be just fine: but if your helper doesn't have a safe way to accept parameter data separate from the sql string, **you're practically begging to get hacked.**

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn no parameters just the query listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use global variables. Return the values out of the method. The calling code should be in charge of placing those values wherever it needs. I recommend reading about [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

```
public WorkerData GetWorkerData()
{
    ...

    using (SqlDataReader reader = ...)
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            return new WorkerData
                {
                    TotalCases4 = reader["DataWin8Data"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["DataWin8Data"].ToString() : string.Empty,
                    TotalCases3 = workerData.TotalPercentage4 = reader["DataWin7Data"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["DataWin7Data"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                }
        }
    }

    throw new ApplicationException("Could not retrieve worker data.");
}
```

From your calling class, simply do whatever you want with the return value:

```
WorkerData workerData = someClass.GetWorkerData();
```

Comment: Alright how would access it without creating a new instance of it on my asp.cs page

Comment: Just call the method like any other method. It sounds like you might need more practice with OOP.

Comment: No kidding is there anything you would recommend to help practice? Book something online?

Comment: Why did you change from using an enumerable method?

Comment: I changed it because your original code only seemed to care about a single `WorkerData` object. If you need to use `IEnumerable<WorkerData>`, it's a pretty simple change.